# RAM upgrade Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: upgrade, 64-bit, android

Currently I am using my Dell Inspiron 1525 for Android development with Android Studio. My laptop has 2 Gb RAM and is running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.
When I only use Android Studio the performance is still acceptable (for me at least).
As soon as I start a second application (Firefox for example) the performance becomes very bad.
Will the performance benefit from an upgrade to 3 or maybe 4 Gb or is the speed of the processor the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a RAM upgrade will always improve performance, especially in your case, where opening multiple large applications slows things down, which is an indication of insufficient memory. You can also check how much memory is in use / available  with the System Monitor tool.

I'd recommend upgrading to as much RAM as possible (4GB), since Android studio needs a lot of memory.